# Edit Single Line XML File In PowerShell Without Changing to Multi-Line XML File

Tags: xml, powershell, line, edit

I have a HUGE XML file that has a whole ton of data packed into a single line.  I've found when I edit that file with PowerShell, it breaks all of the data up into individual lines instead of a single line.  Initially it was changing the encoding from UTF-8 to UTF-8 BOM so I thought that might be the culprit.  I've since fixed that portion of my script and made sure it's still saving as UTF-8 without BOM, but everything is still getting converted from one line to over 600 lines after I run my script.

Anyone know any tricks to keep the formatting on single line xml files when editing in PowerShell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your XML file still fits into memory as an `[xml]` ([`System.Xml.XmlDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlDocument)) DOM:

- When you pass a *file path* to the [`.Save()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlDocument.Save) method, *pretty-printing* of the XML is performed by default.
- To modify this default behavior you must construct a [`System.Xml.XmlWriter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlWriter) instance based on a custom [`System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings) instance that gives you control over the serialization behavior.

  - In fact, such settings default to *not* pretty-print, and would require setting the `.Indent` property to `$true` for pretty-printing.
  - You can also use the `.Encoding` property in order to specify a *BOM-less* UTF-8 encoding, as is your intent.

Here's a self-contained example:

```bash
# Sample input XML
[xml] $xml = '<?xml version="1.0"?><catalog><book id="bk101"><title>De Profundis</title></book></catalog>'

# Create a non-pretty-printing XmlWriter instance 
# with BOM-less UTF-8 encoding that will write to file "test.xml"
# in the current directory.
$writer = [System.Xml.XmlWriter]::Create(
  "$PWD/test.xml", # IMPORTANT: Use a FULL PATH here, because .NET's working dir. usually differs from PowerShell's
  [System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings] @{ Encoding = [Text.UTF8Encoding]::new() }
)

try {
  # Save the document via the writer.
  $xml.Save($writer)
} finally {
  # (Close and) dispose of the writer.
  $writer.Dispose()
}
```